# Rails jQuery UI Draggable Not Working

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I can't seem to figure out why draggable isn't working in my rails app. I'm using the [jquery-ui-rails](https://github.com/jquery-ui-rails/jquery-ui-rails) gem.

In my javascript file I'm including these:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require bootstrap
    //  Angular Stuff
//= require angular
//= require ng-rails-csrf
//= require angular-ui-router
//= require angular-cookies
//= require angular-sanitize
//= require restangular
//= require angular-bootstrap
//= require lodash/lodash.js
//= require angular-rails-templates

//= require spin.js/spin.js
//= require angular-spinner
//= require angular-toastr
//= require moment
//= require moment-timezone
//= require angular-moment
//= require ngstorage

// Core App Files
// = require survey_builder_config
//= require_tree ../survey_builder_app
```

In my scss:

```
@import "jqvmap";
@import "jquery-ui";

@import "bootstrap-switch";
```

In my coffeescript file I'm calling:

```
$scope.refreshOffers = ->
    console.log "refreshOffers"

    $("#drag-me").draggable()
    $("ui-draggable-handle").draggable()
    $(".ui-draggable").draggable()
```

`refreshOffers` does get logged to the console so I know I'm hitting this function. But none of those individually or together seem to make the button draggable.

Here's the HTML (really it's the first button that I'm trying to make draggable though they all should be draggable):

```
<div class="question-types clearfix">
                        <div class="left">
                            <button id="drag-me" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block question-type ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-type="single_select" ng-click="questionClicked"><span></span>Single Selection</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block question-type ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-type="single_select_matrix"><span></span>Single Select Grid</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block question-type ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-type="rating"><span></span>Rating</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block question-type ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-type="short_text_input"><span></span>Short Text</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block question-type ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-type="dropdown"><span></span>Drop Down</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block question-type ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-type="rank_order"><span></span>Ranking</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block question-type ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-type="numeric_input"><span></span>Numeric</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="right">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block question-type ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-type="multiple_select"><span></span>Multiple Selection</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block question-type ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-type="multiple_select_matrix"><span></span>Multiple Select Grid</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block question-type ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-type="descriptive"><span></span>Message</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block question-type ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-type="long_text_input"><span></span>Long Text</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block question-type ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-type="slider"><span></span>Slider</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block question-type ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-type="sum_select"><span></span>Sum</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the answer is that buttons need `cancel: false` set:

```
$(".ui-draggable").draggable({
    cancel: false
})
```